# .net SSL pfx -> The specified network password is not correct

Tags: .net, ssl, x509certificate2, pfx

I am building a website that is connecting to a MySql database on a server that is requiring a SSL certificate. The **Ping** method below is working flowlessly when running it on my local pc but when I am deploying it to our Windows 2008 R2 server, I the following error:
**The specified network password is not correct.**.

I have tried to create a windows form application with the exact same code, and that works perfectly both locally AND on the Windows 2008 R2 server.

Why is the code not working from the website on the shared server?

I can see that others have had the same issue, and suggested to use:

```
new X509Certificate2(Path, "", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
```

but it did not help. Maybe I used it wrongly!?!

```
private bool Ping()
{
    string connectionString = "Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Port=3306;Database=dbname;
            Uid=server1_ssluser;Pwd=xxxxxxxx;SSL Mode=Required;
            CertificateFile=c:\inetpub\xxxxx\App_Data\Certificates\server1\server1.pfx;"

    try
    {
        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString()))
        {
            connection.Open();

            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The specified network password is not correct. 
at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr) 
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._LoadCertFromFile(String fileName, IntPtr password, UInt32 dwFlags, Boolean persistKeySet, SafeCertContextHandle& pCertCtx) 
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromFile(String fileName, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) 
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(String fileName, String password) 
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetClientCertificates() 
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.StartSSL() 
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open() 
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open() 
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings) 
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection() 
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection() 
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver() 
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection() 
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() 
at MvcApplication1.Controllers.ValuesController.Ping()
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the actual problem, but it looks like you're not properly escaping your string. This line:

```
string connectionString = "Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Port=3306;Database=dbname;
        Uid=server1_ssluser;Pwd=xxxxxxxx;SSL Mode=Required;
        CertificateFile=c:\inetpub\xxxxx\App_Data\Certificates\server1\server1.pfx;"
```

should probably be:

```
string connectionString = @"Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Port=3306;Database=dbname;
        Uid=server1_ssluser;Pwd=xxxxxxxx;SSL Mode=Required;
        CertificateFile=c:\inetpub\xxxxx\App_Data\Certificates\server1\server1.pfx;"
```

Otherwise you'll be getting control codes such as `\i` and `\x` in your string.